# Pivot table from a pandas dataframe without an apply function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like that:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'ID' : [2,2,2,2,2,4,4,3,3,3,6] , 'count' : [20,43,45,50,15,65,35,15,15,14,30]})
df
    ID  count
0    2     20
1    2     43 
2    2     45
3    2     50
4    2     15
5    4     65
6    4     35
7    3     15
8    3     15
9    3     14
10   6     30
```

I want to create a pivot table with the following output:

```
ID    1    2    3    4    5
 2   20   43   45   50   15
 4   65   35    0    0    0
 3   15   15   14    0    0
 6   30    0    0    0    0
```

I thought using the pivot function to the dataframe (df_pivot = df.pivot(index='ID', columns=..., values='count') but I am missing the columns index list. I thought applying a lambda function to the df to generate an additional column with the missing column names but I have 800M IDs and the apply function to a grouped dataframe is painfully slow. Is there a quick approach you might be aware off?

Comment: So, you have some function that produces a column name?

Comment: Hi, yes, I thought using the following function:    def f(x): x['Index'] = range(len(x))   return x     and then do the following: df.groupby(['ID']).apply(f)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would define a subindex for each group as:

```
df['subindex'] = df.groupby('ID').cumcount() + 1
```

Then apply the pivot method setting the new `subindex` as columns and fill `NaN` values with 0:

```
d = pd.pivot_table(df,index='ID',columns='subindex',values='count').fillna(0)
```

This returns:

```
subindex   1   2   3   4   5
ID                          
2         20  43  45  50  15
3         15  15  14   0   0
4         65  35   0   0   0
6         30   0   0   0   0
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: perfect! I did not know about cumcount... I guess that I did not have the patience to reach the bottom 95% of the "Groupby" documentation page!